# Paypal Payment Experience web profiles do seem to do anything

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I've created a profile using

```
  var profile_name = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  var create_web_profile_json = {
    "name": profile_name,
    "temporary": false,
    "presentation": {
      "brand_name": "Brand Name",
      "logo_image": "https://www.example.com/logo.png",
      "locale_code": "GB"
    },
    "input_fields": {
      "allow_note": true,
      "no_shipping": 0,
      "address_override": 1
    },
    "flow_config": {
      "landing_page_type": "billing",
      "user_action": "commit"
    }
  };
```

and passed the ID when creating a payment like

```
var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "experience_profile_id": "XX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    }
}
```

but I'm seeing no difference when the paypal express checkout is opened. My logo isn't showing and the customer can select and change their shipping address which they shouldn't be able to do with the profile I've created.